# Local debugging not working on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm getting the following error when I try to debug a simple local "Hello World" application. But the same application runs fine.

```
    FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)
ERROR: transport error 202: connect failed: Connection timed out
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [../../../src/share/back/debugInit.c:750]
```

Debugging local applications used to work on my Eclipse (Kepler on Windows 7). I'm able to ping localhost.

I tried:

1. Turning off firewall.
2. Changing JRE libraries. (changed to jdk)
3. Doing a clean Java Installation.
4. Uncommenting "127.0.0.1 localhost" in etc\hosts

The issue is still not resolved. Is there anything else I can try.

Comment: Are you definitely connecting to localhost? First check in the Debug configuration. Then, you can use a tool like `netstat` or `ss` to verify that it really is trying to connect to localhost.

Comment: I'm not trying to do remote debugging, so I am using the default debug configurations. Also, it used to work fine a week ago, and I'm sure that I haven't changed debug configurations. I can't figure out from the output of "netstat -a" if eclipse is trying to connect to localhost.

Comment: OK, try `netstat -an|fgrep 127.0.0.1` (that's for Linux, other OSs may differ). You should see the connection attempt there, mentioning the (arbitrary) source and (configured) destination port number, if you run it at the right time.

Comment: I tried `netstat -an | find "127.0.0.1"`. I do not see any new connection attempts being made while running eclipse debugger. Also, how do we configure the destination port number in the case of debugging local applications.

Comment: Ah, so this is not a remote debug configuration? i.e. it is an application launched from Eclipse?

Comment: Yes. This is not a remote debug config.

Comment: Try creating a completely fresh debug config. Maybe there is some old stuff in there that's wrong.

Comment: I tried creating new debug config, but still hitting the same issue.

Comment: The issue has been resolved. I had recently upgraded Avast Antivirus. Avast 2014 was causing the issue. I had tried deactivating Avast, but this did not fix the issue. Uninstalling Avast completely fixed the issue. I have switched to Avira now.

Comment: you should post that as an answer and mark it as accepted; that will both close the question and highlight the answer for future visitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved. I had recently upgraded Avast Antivirus. Avast 2014 was causing the issue. I had tried deactivating Avast, but this did not fix the issue. Uninstalling Avast completely fixed the issue. I have switched to Avira now.